# Animation with HTML5

Tags: animation, html

i want to make an animation using HTML5

And i need help with the following:

1- is there an IDE to make it easy to make animation with HTML5
    *like flash IDE with time line ...*

2- What is the best library to make animation with HTML5 
   *i found "burst engine" library it is good but does not handle png images*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Companies are looking seriously at building an IDE for HTML5, including Adobe with their product, [Edge](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/preview-of-the-edge-prototype-tool-for-html5-/), and Microsoft appear to be heading down this route with the [recent announcement](http://gigaom.com/video/microsoft-giving-up-on-silverlight-joining-html5-party/) that they will be abandoning Silverlight as a broader web platform (instead choosing to focus on Windows Phone 7).

Given that HTML5 is still very much on the upward climb in terms of adoption and expectations, many of the higher-profile players in the market (i.e. Adobe, Microsoft, Coda or possibly Eclipse) are still feeling out what constitutes a stable HTML5 feature and what specs are still very fluid, I'd be surprised to see an IDE on the market before this time next year.

So that's my take on IDEs.

In terms of the best library to create HTML5-based animations, it really depends on what you're trying to do.  There are a few JavaScript frameworks out there such as [CakeJS](http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/), [Doodle-js](http://lamberta.org/doodle-js) or - in particular - [ProcessingJs](http://processingjs.org/).

You might find more relevant results for searches that are more specific to your particular needs.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Flash you could try using the following:

[Adobe Wallaby](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/)

This is still on pre-release state, so many features are still unavailable. Here is the list of supported features: [Release Notes](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Wallaby#Release_Notes)

I also found [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcWXsDxWqIE) that gives a basic overview.

Hope it helps! and that soon an actual HTML5 IDE is released...